# Finding $k$ such that a given matrix has a real eigenvalue of algebraic multiplicity $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to find, for which values $k$, the matrix below has a real eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity $2$:

\begin{pmatrix}
-3 & k\\ 
2 & -6
\end{pmatrix}

My work thus far:

$$(-3-λ)(-6-λ)-2K$$

$$λ^2 +9λ+18-2k$$

$$\frac{-9±⌈9-8k⌉}{2}$$

I'm not sure where to go on from here to solve this.

Comment: Hint: A quadratic will have repeated roots if $b^2-4ac=0$.

Answer (score -1):

For us to have a double root (i.e. an algebraic multiplicity of two), the discriminant of the characteristic equation must be zero. This holds for quadratics in general: if $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ has a root of multiplicity two - a double root - then $b^2 - 4ac = 0$.

---

The characteristic equation in this case is

$$\lambda^2 + 9\lambda + (18-2k) = 0$$

and the discriminant being the rooted expression in the quadratic formula, which, here, is

$$9^2 - 4(1)(18-2k) = 81 - (72-8k) = 9 + 8k$$

So, for the discriminant to be zero, we require

$$9+8k = 0$$

Only one $k$ satisfies this equation, and I imagine you can find it pretty easily.

Comment: Is this true for algebraic multiplicity that are greater than 1. If i wanted distinct roots then 9+8k can't equal zero, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on the characteristic equation involved. For example, for a cubic characteristic equation, you will need to utilize some other technique to figure out the roots and their respective multiplicities. It just so happens for quadratics that we have this nice property.

Comment: How about in the case of distinct roots

Comment: If the roots are all distinct, they have algebraic multiplicity $1$, and the discriminant in the quadratic case will be nonzero. (It will be greater than zero if we only want real roots.)

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Cubics and quartics also have discriminants that tell you the nature of the roots when the coefficients are real.

Comment: Huh. Thanks for the heads up, I'll look into it. (Though of course the answer is still "it depends," because of quintics and higher degrees being unsolvable by radicals. :p)